# Correct term to describe apparent bias in expressing opinions -- extremity as a function of publicity

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the proper term to describe the apparent bias that exists in voicing one's opinion. Here are two ways I currently conceptualize this bias:

- the content of the comparatively more outspoken individuals are more
  opinionated/extreme
- the more public/widespread a message is, the more opinionated/extreme
  it tends to be

.There is a bit of nuance that sets the above explanations apart, but they loosely govern the same principal. Principal may even be a bit of a strong word, I admit, it's almost akin to a generalization. Nonetheless, there are certainly some sociological/psychological mechanisms at work, so my hope is that there is an existing term for this. It might be helpful to include a quick example/anecdote:

**Example 1:** When one looks at graffiti messages on walls, they tend to make a distinct stance on something. It would be much more likely to see "Chuck Norris is awesome!" or "Chuck Norris is stupid!" written on a wall than it would be to see "Chuck Norris is so-so."

Bear in mind I'm not grappling with causality or anything, merely correlation. It could very well be that more opinionated messages are more entertaining, sell more views, or what have you. I simply wish to find the proper term for this phenomenon or have the phrase I coined criticized.

**Optional**

If there is truly no existing term for this bias, I would like to include an optional section for addressing the term I coined for it, which is: "Extrema Bias". It has a nice ring to it, I'm not sure if the etymology is justified by the word roots though.

Comment: Bias is the word, why use another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an example of *survival bias*, a type of *selection bias*. Survival bias refers to erroneously drawing conclusions from just the data that survive a filtering process.

In your example, less extreme opinions are filtered out because it’s only the extremists who go to the trouble of trumpeting their views. Similarly, job satisfaction surveys are only filled out by people who still work at the company. (“[Survivorship Bias](https://youarenotsosmart.com/2013/05/23/survivorship-bias/)”, *You Are Not So Smart: A Celebration of Self Delusion*, 2013) An example given in *Wikipedia* is that failed companies are often excluded from studies of financial performance because they are no longer around to be studied. This skews the study results. (“[Survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias)”, *Wikipedia*)

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. Contrary to my initial understanding, I suppose it's also correlation that the publicly viewable opinions (data) are extreme. Could survival bias also explain the sensationalism present in the media? e.g., only the most knee-jerking stories get generous air time? It seems to be the same idea, right?

Comment: Less extreme stories filtered out? Yes, and sometimes for a more cynical reason. Some news networks circulate sensational articles because sensationalism attracts more subscribers.